# Login and registration page path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am a newbie in C# programming and web development. Kindly let me know how I can find the code files for the login and register page in ASP.NET MVC.

I created this simple web app using this crash course; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfEjDD8mWYg&t=909s.

This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joWtK.png) of the page I want to locate and alter. I want to change the text next to the login and registration forms.

Looking forward to getting a reply from anyone who can help.

Thanks in advance

I tried looking in all the files, like the css file and all the files in the views folder, but I could not find the file I want to change the text on the registration and login page.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that how you created this page?? Because mostly html contents are in views folder

Comment: What platform are you on? The title and one tag mention "ASP.NET MVC" (which is the full, classic, WIndows-only **.NET** framework), while you also have an `asp.net-core` tag which refers to the modern, cross-plattform **.NET Core** framework - which one are you using?  They are very similar - but not identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the video you provided and find that he created a project with `Individual User Accounts`, So the project will generate `Register` and `Login` page Automatically, But you can't find these pages in your project.

If you wanna find these pages, You need to `Scaffold Identity`:

- From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New
  Scaffolded Item
  .
- From the left pane of the Add New Scaffolded Item    dialog, select
  Identity. Select Identity in the center pane. Select    the Add
  button.

[image]

Select pages you want to create, Here you can choose Login and Register page, Then To use your existing data context, select at least one file to override. You must select at least one file to add your data context.

After you finish these steps and generate page successfully, You will find these pages in `Area/Identity/Pages/Account/...` ,Then you can edit them.

[image]

More information you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization).